# Removing BoxedUnit from a List in Scala (aka "How I collect values from a stored procedure)

Tags: scala, jdbc

I have a function that will execute SQL stored functions fairly elegantly: It takes the parameters as a List[ProcedureParameters]. The ProcedureParameters can get In, InOut, or Out.

When I get the return values from the procedure, I collect them like this:

```
val results: List[Any] = for (parameter <- ps.parameters) yield {
    index = index + 1
    parameter match {
        case Out(Types.BIGINT) => cs.getLong(index)
        case Out(Types.INTEGER) => cs.getInt(index)
        // Lots more SQL to Java specific mapping here...
    }
}
```

This does a pretty good job of iterating over the List of ProcedureParameters and, if there is an Out (or an InOut) parameter, it gets the value.

But if there is **not** a value, I get a `BoxedUnit`.

The `results` list, then, comes back like this:

> List(3007, (), (), (), (), (), (), 0)

First thing I tried was to filter out the BoxedUnit instances, but I can't seem to find a way to do it. `.filter(_ != BoxedUnit)` won't work since BoxedUnit is not a value...

Then I started working on a way to modify my for comprehension (or the yield statement) so it only yields "real" values (that means, either None or Some instance) but, still stuck on that.

Any advice would be deeply appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: where are these types defined? InOut, Out? or what is the type of `parameter`?

Comment: you could try to do this: `for {parameter <- ps.parameters if parameter != BoxedUnit.UNIT } yield { ... same code here }`. I'm not completely sure if it will work because `parameter` type is unknown to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.filter(_ != (()))
```

`BoxedUnit` is an implementation detail that apparently leaked in your use case. It's the reification on the JVM of the `Unit` type, and thus its only instance is the good old `()` that we know to be the only value of type `Unit`.

Comment: Thanks! I'd never run into it before... While experimenting I also found out that you can get rid of it with this: `results.filter(_ != scala.runtime.BoxedUnit.UNIT)`

Comment: Yes, that would work too, since `scala.runtime.BoxedUnit.UNIT` is the implementation detail that is the encoding of `()`. You should use `()` though, because everything under `scala.runtime.*` is subject to change or removal without notice.